# Fallo al referenciar hojas de estilo(css) y javascript en proyecto ASP.NET MVC 5 con Razor

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5, layout

Buenas tardes,tengo una mi web en ASP .NET MVC . Actualmente estoy implementando el Layout(Ubicado en **Yanbal**(la solución de VS)->**Views**->**Shared**->**_Layout.css**. He hecho un modelo en wordpress. Obtuve el código html de éste y copié lo que me interesaba en mi web(La Cabecera). Vi que en el archivo html,referenciaba hojas de estilo y archivos javascript; entonces copie dichos archivos en mi Solución y los coloqué en una carpeta llamada "FormatoLayout".

Nota: Algunos archivos no tienen el formato css simplemente son archivos sin formato(xxxxxx en vez de xxxxxx.css), no creo que tenga que ver algo o sí?

**Mi Workspace:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
<link href="~/Content/selimain.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<script defer="" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/FormatoLayout/beacon.js.descarga")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    function addLoadEvent(func) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function () {
                oldonload();
                func();
            }
        }
    }
    /* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s0.wp.com\/wp-content\/mu-plugins\/wpcom-smileys\/twemoji\/2\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s0.wp.com\/wp-content\/mu-plugins\/wpcom-smileys\/twemoji\/2\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"https:\/\/s1.wp.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?m=1496863874h&ver=4.8-RC2-40878"}};
        !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var b,c,d,e,f=String.fromCharCode;if(!k||!k.fillText)return!1;switch(k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.textBaseline="top",k.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return k.fillText(f(55356,56826,55356,56819),0,0),b=j.toDataURL(),k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55356,56826,8203,55356,56819),0,0),c=j.toDataURL(),b===c&&(k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447),0,0),b=j.toDataURL(),k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447),0,0),c=j.toDataURL(),b!==c);case"emoji4":return k.fillText(f(55358,56794,8205,9794,65039),0,0),d=j.toDataURL(),k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55358,56794,8203,9794,65039),0,0),e=j.toDataURL(),d!==e}return!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.defer=c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g,h,i,j=b.createElement("canvas"),k=j.getContext&&j.getContext("2d");for(i=Array("flag","emoji4"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},h=0;h<i.length;h++)c.supports[i[h]]=d(i[h]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[i[h]],"flag"!==i[h]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[i[h]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/FormatoLayout/wp-emoji-release.min.js.descarga")" type="text/javascript" defer=""></script>
<style type="text/css">
    img.wp-smiley,
    img.emoji {
        display: inline !important;
        border: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        height: 1em !important;
        width: 1em !important;
        margin: 0 .07em !important;
        vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
        background: none !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="all-css-0-1" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/FormatoLayout/saved_resource")" type="text/css" media="all">
<style id="wpcom-admin-bar-inline-css" type="text/css">
    .goog-te-banner-frame {
        top: 32px !important;
    }
</style>
<style id="edin-style-inline-css" type="text/css">
    .hero.with-featured-image {
        background-image: url(https://proyectoyanbal.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/144403.jpg?w=1230);
    }

    .hero.without-featured-image {
        background-image: url();
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="print-css-1-1" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/FormatoLayout/global-print.css")" type="text/css" media="print">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="goran-noto-sans-css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/FormatoLayout/css")" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="goran-noto-serif-css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/FormatoLayout/css(1)")" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="goran-droid-sans-mono-css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/FormatoLayout/css(2)")" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="all-css-8-1" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/FormatoLayout/saved_resource(1)")" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/FormatoLayout/saved_resource(2)")"></script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="https://proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd">
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="https://s1.wp.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml">
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress.com">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com/">
<link rel="shortlink" href="http://wp.me/P8T4gX-2">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="https://public-api.wordpress.com/oembed/?format=json&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fproyectoyanbal.wordpress.com%2F&amp;for=wpcom-auto-discovery">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/xml+oembed" href="https://public-api.wordpress.com/oembed/?format=xml&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fproyectoyanbal.wordpress.com%2F&amp;for=wpcom-auto-discovery">
<!-- Jetpack Open Graph Tags -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Proyecto Yanbal">
<meta property="og:description" content="Web Site para realizar compras desde la página web de la empresa">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com/">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Proyecto Yanbal">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://proyectoyanbal.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/144403.jpg?w=1200">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400">
<meta property="og:locale" content="es_ES">

<meta name="twitter:text:title" content="Página de inicio">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://proyectoyanbal.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/144403.jpg?w=640">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="249643311490">
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/WordPresscom">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://s2.wp.com/i/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16 24x24 32x32 48x48">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://s2.wp.com/i/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16 24x24 32x32 48x48">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="https://s0.wp.com/i/webclip.png">
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="https://proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com/osd.xml" title="Proyecto Yanbal">
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="https://s1.wp.com/opensearch.xml" title="WordPress.com">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#e1dfdf">
<meta name="application-name" content="Proyecto Yanbal">
<meta name="msapplication-window" content="width=device-width;height=device-height">
<meta name="msapplication-tooltip" content="Web Site para realizar compras desde la página web de la empresa">
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Editar página;action-uri=https://wordpress.com/page/proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com/2;icon-uri=https://s0.wp.com/i/icons/page.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Escribir una entrada;action-uri=https://wordpress.com/post/proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com;icon-uri=https://s2.wp.com/i/icons/post.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Moderar comentarios;action-uri=https://proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php?comment_status=moderated;icon-uri=https://s0.wp.com/i/icons/comment.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Subir archivos multimedia;action-uri=https://proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com/wp-admin/media-new.php;icon-uri=https://s2.wp.com/i/icons/media.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Estadísticas del blog;action-uri=https://proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com/wp-admin/index.php?page=stats;icon-uri=https://s1.wp.com/i/icons/stats.ico">
<meta name="title" content="Página de inicio | Proyecto Yanbal en WordPress.com">
<meta name="description" content="Este es el extracto de la página de inicio">
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    #wpadminbar {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
* html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
@@media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
    html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
}
</style>
<style type="text/css" id="syntaxhighlighteranchor"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="gravatar-card-css" href="./FormatoLayout/hovercard.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="gravatar-card-services-css" href="./FormatoLayout/services.css">
</head>
<body class="home page-template page-template-page-templates page-template-front-page page-template-page-templatesfront-page-php page page-id-2 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support mp6 customizer-styles-applied hero-image has-quinary has-custom-background has-footer-navigation navigation-default no-sidebar-full highlander-enabled highlander-light small-screen medium-screen large-screen">
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="https://proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com/#content">Saltar al contenido.</a>
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="display: block; margin-bottom: -96px;">
        <div class="site-top-content">
            Edit this message in the <a href="https://wordpress.com/customize/">Customizer (Theme Options)</a>
        </div><!-- .site-top-content -->

        <div class="site-branding">
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="https://proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com/" rel="home">Proyecto Yanbal</a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description">Web Site para realizar compras desde la página web de la empresa</h2>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle">Menú</button>
            <div class="menu-primary">
                <ul id="menu-primary" class="clear">
                    <li id="menu-item-12" class="inicio menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-12">@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li id="menu-item-13" class="devoluciones menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13">@Html.ActionLink("Contáctanos", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li id="menu-item-14" class="contacto menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14">@Html.ActionLink("Contáctanos", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li id="menu-item-15" class="administracion menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15">@Html.ActionLink("ADMINISTRACIÓN", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
    <div id="content" class="site-content">


        <div class="hero with-featured-image" style="padding-top: 312px;">

            <article id="post-2" class="post-2 page type-page status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">
                <div class="entry-content">
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                <footer class="entry-footer"><span class="edit-link"><a class="post-edit-link" href="https://wordpress.com/page/proyectoyanbal.wordpress.com/2">Editar</a></span></footer>
            </article><!-- #post-## -->
        </div><!-- .hero -->

        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <footer>


            <div id="textopie">
                <strong>Yanbal™</strong> <br />
                Teléfono: +51(01)553-8511<br />
                email: contacto@yanbal.com.pe<br />
                www.yanbal.pe
            </div>
            <div id="imagenpie">
                <img src="~/images/fb.png" />
                <img src="~/images/yt.png" />
                <img src="~/images/tw.png" />
            </div>

        </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>    
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo estás llamando los estilos en tu vista? O en Layout_cshtml

Comment: En la Vista no los he referenciado,solo en el Layout.cshtml

Comment: Anteriormente hice un diseño para mi Layout con una hoja de estilos dentro de la carpeta Content y se ejecutó correctamente. No necesité llamar los estilos en la vista (list_usu)

Comment: J.Carlos , es la carpeta correcta donde van los estilos , y tampoco es necesario añadirlos a la vista si ya la vista extiende del `layout.cshtml` , por eso añada la forma donde llama a los estilos en su `layout.cshtml`

Comment: Entiendo,está se encuentra en la parte negra de la imágen que posteé. Es decir: http://oi63.tinypic.com/6xsun4.jpg

Comment: edita tu pregunta, agrega el código del _layout.cshtml

Comment: J.Carlos en la imagen no se visualizan los `link` a los estilos por los que se presentan los errores. es decir de `hovercard.css` ,tampoco de `services.css` , los demás errores está claro que les hace falta la extensión en la ruta y en los archivos si no, se tomarán como carpetas

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta pudo solucionar tu pregunta?

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta pudo solucionar tu pregunta? x2

Comment: Sí,claro que sí. La segunda respuesta,sin embargo no puedo calificarla como "solución" como tal,ya que no tengo el rango requerido :/. Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el archivo y su falta de extensión .css

La primera línea está bien hecha ya que el archivo contiene su extensión:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/FormatoLayout/global-print.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Realiza lo mismo con los demás: primero edita los nombres de archivos y luego llámalos correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Usa el **BundleConfig.cs** para agregar en cada vista los **js** y **css** con  `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` y/o `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")` *(mira bien comom lo defines para "invocarlos")*.

Te sugiero mantengas la estructura lo más apegada a los "normal" que debe ser; los *.[cs|vb]html (segun C# o VB) en **Views**, los *.css en Content (salvo uses Nuget que dependiendo el paquete algunas veces crea Scripts y allí le coloca sus css); bueno ya indistintamente lo coloques "en su lugar" o como ya lo tengas hacer uso **BoundleConfig.cs** y allí declarar según corresponda e inlcuirlos ya sea en tu layout oen cada vista

Éxito y suerte.